# Calculating current flow through the Earth attached to an ohmmeter

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, geophysics

If I wanted to measure the resistance of the Earth between two points at its surface, I could, in principle, connect a simple ohmmeter to the two points and read out the apparent resistance just like when measuring the resistance of any other circuit.

Now, if the Earth could be described as a half space with a uniform resistivity $\rho$, is it then possible to calculate what apparent resistance $R$ an ohmmeter would measure, if the two electrodes were positioned at a distance $a$ between each other, and assuming that they can be regarded as points with small depth relative to their individual distance?

Within geophysics there is dedicated field of study, geoelectrics, with well established procedures and theories for doing something similar: Estimating Earth resistivity by injecting current into the Earth and measuring associated electric potential differences. The common practice is to use one pair of electrodes to inject current into the Earth and then use another pair of electrodes to measure potential differences at multiple locations.

The question I pose here is in a sense a special case of the two above 4-electrode situation, where a potential is measured across the two current injection electrodes. The problem is that the usual theory then breaks down (at least for me). Let me explain:

If a current $I$ is injected at a single electrode above a half space, conservation of charge and ohms law imply that a potential $V$ relative to the electrode at distance $r$ from the electrode, can be expressed as:

$V=\frac{-I\rho}{2\pi r}$

With two current electrodes (a source $A$ and a sink $B$) with currents $I$ and $-I$ respectively, superposition may be applied, and a potential due to the two electrodes would then be:

$V_{ab}=\frac{I\rho}{2\pi}(\frac{1}{r_A}-\frac{1}{r_B})  $ at a point where distance to electrode $A$ is $r_A$ and distance to electrode $B$ is $r_B$

Source: [https://sites.ualberta.ca/~unsworth/UA-classes/325/C/325C2-2005.pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Eunsworth/UA-classes/325/C/325C2-2005.pdf)

With this, it is possible to calculate the potential difference at any (almost) two electrodes that might be used in a geoelectric survey. This is in turn used to measure what is called the apparent resistivity structure of the earth.

However, when applying the above, simple theory to the first-mentioned ohmmeter example, we run into a singularity, because we now want to calculate the potential difference between the current electrodes at distance zero which we of course don't want to divide with.

But what does this singularity mean in this context? What assumptions break down? I am confused, because in the real world it is possible to e.g. connect a car battery to a conductive soil, measure a current running through the associated circuit as well as a voltage drop. Just like when measuring current and voltage in any other simple electric circuit.

Something tells me that the problem arises because point electrodes have zero surrounding control area, and hence current density and electric field would be infinitely high at such location. Practically, electrodes have finite contact area with the Earth, and so, given a fixed electromotive force, the amount of current would increase with increased contact area. However, if this is the culprit, then I am not sure why the above geoelectric theory works well in all the other non-ohmmeter situations.

Comment: If you measure with only two electrodes, the measured resistance will probably depend a great deal on the size and shape of the electrodes (the surface area between them and the earth, etc). If you use 4 electrodes you can probably treat them all as point contacts.

Comment: You can not "inject" current at a single  electrode. for a current you need allways two.